# How can I display a mat-icon as disabled

Tags: angular, material-ui

I'm working on an Angular application containing a mat-accordion component with several panels. A panel can be either enabled or disabled. I use a material-ui icon to indicate this. if a panel is enabled I display the check_circle mat-icon. If a panel is disabled I display the hourglass_bottom mat icon.
Currently the hourglass_bottom icon is displayed in a blue color. I want it to be displayed in grey color, indicating the panel is disabled.
I have this:

```
  <mat-icon
    [ngClass]="{'icon-accordeon': true, 'disabled': !hasStatusGeleverd}">
      {{hasStatusGeleverd ? 'check_circle' : 'hourglass_bottom'}}
  </mat-icon>
```

Currently I apply a class to the button to indicate the disabled state:

```
.mat-icon {
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($palette-politie-blauw, 700);

    &.disabled {
        color: gray;
    }
}
```

...but that is no material-ui style of course. I expected an attribute [disabled]="true" to exist but it doesn't do anything. I cannot find a disabled material-ui style I can apply conditionally. Using a button element and adding the mat-icon attribute...

```
<button mat-icon ...>...</button>
```

...as suggested in 'How to make mat-icon disabled in Angular'doesn't work - a normal button gets displayed instead. Probably because the mat-icon element is a child of a <mat-expansion-panel => mat-accordion?
Adding color="disabled"

```
 <mat-icon
        color="disabled"
        class="icon-accordeon">
```

...has no effect either.

Is it possible to display an icon as disabled?

"@angular/core": "^12.2.16",

"@angular/material": "^12.2.13",

Answer (score 1):

Use mat-icon inside the **button tag** and then you can use disabled
OtherWise custom class is a good approach

Comment: Thanks. What material-ui class is used to style an icon as disabled?

Comment: create your custom class

.disable{ 
pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.5;}
I hope It will help you..